# Построение графика одномерного массива maple

Tags: maple

подскажите как построить график одномерного массива в maple по его данным, мне выдает прямую хотя это не так?

```
   > restart;
   > Digits := 4;
   fd := fopen(`C:\\Учеба\\Мат.модели\\Вакансия Электротех\\test1.txt`, READ)
    L := readdata(fd, 1)
    with(linalg)
    count := nops(L)
    A := array(1 .. count, L)
    plot(A);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код-то покажите, которым строите.

Comment: Код написал посмотрите

Comment: И данные массива. Вдруг там реально прямая )

Comment: В массиве 6138 элеменетов, это экспериментальные данные ну там что-то типа 1,999 около 500 раз, и т.д. заканчиваеся 1,41 около 500 раз, по данному коду картина вообще вот такая

Comment: мне нужна зависимость от номера элемента

Comment: Похоже, оси у вас перепутаны. Получается N графиков, в каждом одна точка, а нужно 1 график c N точек. Подозреваю, что A получается двумерным массивом [N, 1], а не просто [N].

Comment: кстати да, как это здесь исправить?

Comment: читайте документацию )) Я в Maple в 2003м в последний раз работал, уже не помню.

Comment: `plot(L)` не сработает?

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно. На картинке 6138 графиков. Каждая горизонтальная линия есть график постоянной функции, причём эти константы разбросаны примерно от 1.4 до 2.

Так как plot вызвана с одним аргументом, то графики строятся от -10 до 10 (по умолчанию)